# Why the code after exception raised in try block is not executed? if the exception is not handled ,then the control goes out?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

```
class TestFinallyBlock1{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        try{  
            int data=25/0;  
            System.out.println(data);  
        }  
        catch(NullPointerException e){System.out.println(e);}  
        finally{System.out.println("finally block is always executed");}  
        System.out.println("rest of the code...");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Output:finally block is always executed
            Exception in thread main java.lang.ArithmeticException:/ by zero

Comment: It always happens that whether the exception handled or not ,the code after the exception line of code in try block is never executed, why that so??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can understand the behaviour if you extract method and add the additional try-catch block as follows:

```
public class TestFinallyBlock1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            throwArithmeticException();
            System.out.println("rest of the code...");
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void throwArithmeticException() {
        try {
            int data = 25 / 0;
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally block is always executed");
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, please refer to [Java Language Specification - Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)